# Role.addToPolicy() only on new Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

Why is the `addtoPolicy` method not available on the Role object if I get an existing role by name (or by arn)? The `fromRoleName` method should return a `Role` object. For example:

```
let testRole=Role.fromRoleName(this,"test-role","test-role");
testRole.addToPolicy()//Method not found
```

On the other hand, this works:

```
testRole = new Role(this,"test-role", {
  assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com')
})
testRole.addToPolicy() //OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because fromRoleName returns an [IRole interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.IRole.html). This interface does not have a `addToPolicy` method.